# Linear layout background color not changing programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, background-color

I'm creating an Activity Log for Lock and Unlock times, and I need my background color sorted according to Lock or Unlock. However, I cant seem to change the background color of my linear layout no matter what I put. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

This is my main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private List<ListItem> listItems;

DatabaseReference database;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    final LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.damsi);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences(LOCK_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Activity Log/device321");

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot usersnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) usersnapshot.getValue();
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().equals("LockTime")) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB71616"));
                    }
                    if (entry.getKey().equals("UnlockTime")) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB71616"));
                    }
                    listItems.add(new ListItem(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }


                //   ListItem listItem = usersnapshot.getValue(ListItem.class);
            }
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

This is My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/damsi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#baa40f"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewHead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Heading"

android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Description" />
    </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ListItem> listItems;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);


    holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
    holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public LinearLayout layout;
    public TextView textViewHead;
    public TextView textViewDesc;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
        textViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);

    }
}


}
```

Comment: what exact output are you getting??

Comment: the output i'm getting is the android background color i added in the XML document. i tried removing the XML background color , still no luck. I cant change anything in the list_items XML document. Is the problem my layout inflator??

Comment: can u remove the final from the linear layout

Comment: did that as well. No luck. I just cant figure out the problem

Comment: declare the linear layout as instance variable

Comment: u have decalred it inside oncreate

Comment: and change the hex color

Comment: both are having same hex color

Comment: did it work after changes??

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: are u getting any exceptions??

Comment: can u show me the code of myadpater??

Comment: done. check the edited code :)

Comment: did u try the changes??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this code from MainActivity

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        final LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.damsi);
```

Remove these lines from OnDataChangedMethod

```
if (entry.getKey().equals("LockTime")) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB71616"));
                    }
                    if (entry.getKey().equals("UnlockTime")) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB71616"));
                    }
```

In your ViewHolder class, add these lines in your viewholder constructor.

```
layout= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.damsi);
```

Add these lines in onBindViewHolder method.

```
String key = listItem.getHead();
if(key.equals("LockTime"))
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB71616"));
}
if(key..equals("UnlockTime")){
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF001600"));
    //I changed the color as both were having same hexcodes :P
}
holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());
```

Comment: I have a small doubt though, Why wasn't i able to change anything in the main activity?

Comment: onBindViewHolder method is the place where the list items are bounded to xml for recycler view.and during main acitivty that reference to acces linear layout would have no impact as onbindviewholder would have redrawn the layout and data